# ember.js - Can't get ember example working in jsFiddle

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, jsfiddle

Could someone help me to get this http://jsfiddle.net/FLxgH/6/ working?

It works on my computer where I've been using local versions of the libs handlebars.js, ember.js and ember-data.js (downloaded from ember.js - starter pack).

I thought I had found online-equivelants (see External Resources) but it stops the application working when I try and use those references locally, and is possibly the reason why the jsFiddle doesnt work, too.

Locally I get: "Uncaught TypeError: Object function ..." on ember-latest-min.js:11

These are the references I am using:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.0/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember.js/1.0.0-rc.6/ember.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember-data.js/0.8.0-latest20121123/ember-data-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not really sure what would cause this but first of all you should be using handlebars-rc.4 with ember-rc.6, I had some crashes because of that even when testing it in my project. Though it didn't solve your problem I'm afraid.

Comment: does it work for you now?

Comment: great thanks..but i've broken it again with the actual issue i'm tyring to solve - see my comment in your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your jsfiddle, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kxhUw/).
Now it's working.

- http://builds.emberjs.com/handlebars-1.0.0.js
- http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-latest.js
- http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-data-latest.js

This are the resources that work well togheter.

```
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/handlebars-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/ember-data-latest.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks VERY much. That's allowed me to pose the actual problem I need help with: [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532131/ember-js-model-data-is-not-being-output-by-the-collectionview)