# ember.js model data is not being output by the collectionView

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

I am at sea, and would be grateful for any help, with the latest version of Ember. Using the [todo](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/)  example, i've tried to include routes and DS models in the following adapted http://jsfiddle.net/5HMzu/3/

When I use a #each controller in the handlebar template, output is as expected; replacing that with a CollectionView and trying to tie that to the data source, nothing is being output.

The inserted code:

```
App.PersonCollectionView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
itemViewClass: "App.ListOfPeopleTemplateView",
emptyView: Ember.View.extend({
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("Oh dear, the collectionView is empty")
}),
 contentBinding: "App.listOfpeopleTemplateController"
```

});

Result: "Oh dear, the collectionView is empty"

TEMPLATE

```
<body>  
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <!-- an attempt to show the data template 'listOfPeopleTemplate' using a CollectionView -->
    {{view App.PersonCollectionView}}    
</script>    
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="listOfPeopleTemplate">       
    {{test}}
    <!-- This was working before I removed the #each and tried to use a CollectionView -->
    <!-- {{#each controller}} -->
    <fieldset>              
        <label {{bindAttr for="view.tbFullName.elementId"}}>Full Name</label>
        {{view App.DetailTextField viewName="tbFullName" placeholder="Full Name" valueBinding="fullName" readonly="readonly"}}                  
        <br/>
        <label {{bindAttr for="view.tbFirstName.elementId"}} class="RequiredLabel">First Name</label>
        {{view App.DetailTextField viewName="tbFirstName" valueBinding="firstName"}}
        <br/>                   
        <label {{bindAttr for="view.tbSurname.elementId"}} class="RequiredLabel">Surname</label>
        {{view App.DetailTextField viewName="tbSurname" placeholder="surname" valueBinding="surname"}}
        <br/>                   
    </fieldset>
    <!-- {{/each}} -->
</script>
```

JS

```
//the application
App = Ember.Application.create();
//the models
App.PersonModel=DS.Model.extend({
    personID: DS.attr('number'),
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    surname: DS.attr('string'),
    fullName: Ember.computed(function () {
        return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('surname');
        // Tell Ember that this computed property depends on firstName
        // and lastName
    }).property('firstName', 'surname')
});

App.Store=DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});
App.PersonModel.FIXTURES = [{
    id: 1,
    "personID": "1",
    "firstName": "small",
    "surname": "Hick"   
}, {
    id: 2,
    "personID": "2",
    "firstName": "Katherine",
    "surname": "Hosh"   
}];

App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('listOfPeopleTemplate', { path: '/' });
});
//Defining a resource 'listOfPeopleTemplate' will make ember automatically generate a ListOfPeopleTemplateRoute, a ListOfPeopleTemplateController and a ListOfPeopleTemplateView
//You can override this default setup by defining them yourself. This I have done below.

App.ListOfPeopleTemplateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.PersonModel.find();
    }
});
App.ListOfPeopleTemplateController=Ember.ArrayController.extend({   
    test:"does this work test"  
});

App.ListOfPeopleTemplateView=Ember.View.extend({templateName:"listOfPeopleTemplate"});

App.DetailTextField = Em.TextField.extend({
    attributeBindings: ['required', 'readonly', 'name']
});
//New code added to try and use the handlebar template with an ember.collectionView
App.listOfpeopleTemplateController=App.ListOfPeopleTemplateController.create();
 App.PersonCollectionView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
    itemViewClass: "App.ListOfPeopleTemplateView",
    emptyView: Ember.View.extend({
        template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("Oh dear, the collectionView is empty")
    }),
     contentBinding: "App.listOfpeopleTemplateController"   
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things amiss here.

- You never directly instantiate a controller, Ember does this for you. Avoid `SomeController.create`
- When you switched to the `CollectionView` you need to give it what property to bind to, in this case content.
- You provided this directly on the `PersonCollectionView`, but the binding assumes a static path to a controller. This doesn't work with Ember's Container anymore. You can provide a `controllerBinding`, but that assumes that the route and model for that controller has the model. In this case you are still on the `application` route. Typically you just set the `content` in the template.

I believe most of these things are due to referencing tutorials/code for older Ember versions. Ember has changed significantly since and Unfortunately, a lot of example code found online is now out of date.

I fixed things up a bit [here](http://jsfiddle.net/S5bUW/1/), by putting things inside `ApplicationRoute`, adding `contentBinding`, etc.

A few suggestions I can make,

- Try going through the [Ember getting started guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started) start to finish.
- Go through sample examples like [this](https://github.com/emberjs-seattle/ember-reader), and try to rebuild them from scratch.
- Avoid `CollectionView`, and use `#each`, and `{{outlet}}`. CollectionView is only needed for specialized cases, like rendering a 10,000+ items in a list etc. `#each` is internally implemented with a much smarter `CollectionView`.

Comment: Thank you. There's clearly more of the coneceptual framework to learn. It's very frustrating to find my app broken using the latest libraries. TAKING your lead, I will go back to #each BUT i thought this was why I could not bindAttr the label For to the field: ember just links it to the last record, not to each record's input field (so that when the user clicks on the label, the correct input field is highlighted).