# ember not working on jsfiddle

Tags: ember.js, jsfiddle

For some reason ember won't work in jsfiddle at the moment.  And, I mean it won't work for my [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/martinp999/KGHYe/5/), it won't work for other fiddles such as [this starter kit](http://jsfiddle.net/odigity/PkT8x/), or [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/craig/MBmUs/2/), or either of the fiddles in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530818/ember-js-cant-get-ember-example-working-in-jsfiddle).

I've tried this on Chrome and Firefox on two different machines.  And, on my example, I've tried a range of CDNs, methods of including the libraries, versions, body declarations and actual code.

I must be doing something dumb because I keep getting different errors depending on which example I look at, which seems to indicate something fundamentally wrong but I assume jsfiddle works (or worked) in general.

Is anyone else seeing the same thing as me?

```
Apparently, posts with links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code now?  I've seen other posts with jsfiddle links and no code?  Isn't this the whole point of jsfiddle? Well, here's the code.
```

Comment: And the intent of the jsfiddle link code requirement is to allow stackoverflow questions to stand on their own even if jsfiddle closes or is not accessible: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the app initialization script:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();
```

and wrap your handlebars in the correct `<script>` tags:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
....
</script>
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KGHYe/6/)

Comment: Awesome! Many thanks.  I guess that I was thrown by all the other examples that weren't working either.  I'm guessing that they might not have been working due to older versions of ember?  Any ideas?

Comment: Yup, It looks like the other ones are using old versions of libraries or have other issues from being out of date.